# After update CiviCRM IATS Extension to 1.7.4, Card on file and Expiry Date fields are not showing

Tags: civicontribute, civicrm-home, iats, iatspayments

When we create a new iATS recurring donation, we can edit the payment information, but the old iATS recurring donations cannot be updated. I have checked in extension code getting the customer code by payment_token_id. But payment_token_id  is missing in ContributionRecur API response. Only issue is in old (before update extension) iATS recurring donations.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have upgraded the extension 1.6.2 to 1.7.4. During upgraded extension upgrade function were not ruined upgrade_1_7_002 and upgrade_1_7_003. After manually run the SQL Queries issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for posting your question and answering it. FWIW, the 1.7 has some db changing bits in it and that's why the upgrade steps needed to run. Before 1.7, the extension was managing the customer tokens itself, but as of 1.7 it converted to using the civi-native token api/system.

Comment: @AlanDixon Recurring payment started at January 19th, 2021.I changed the next contribution date from February 19th to February 2nd, 2021. It was working February 2nd, 2021 , March 2nd, 2021 and April 2nd, 2021. I have updated the IATS extension after upgraded it charged at May 5th, 2021 instead of May 2th, 2021.
This happened with multiple users. Is there a way to see if it is based on an iATS update?